# Hyperlink with mentions preferred browser

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Here is the situation :

I am creating a static webpage which has hyperlinks to various external webpages.

These external webpages are not cross-browser compatible. I mean, a certain page is optimized for IE while the other(to which my static page points to) is optimized for Firefox.

Question :
Is there a way in which I ( the writer of static webpage ) can dictate that when clicked, a hyperlink should be opened in a certain browser ( if available on client machine ) ?
Something in which link can express its preference for browser.

Reason for asking this question is that when user is clicking through hyperlinks on my static page, they all open in default browser at client machine. Now, if the link is not optimized for default browser, he/she will often have to reopen those links in browser for which the individual link is optimized. This is very cumbersome.

Comment: Do you really have to link to pages that you know/believe to be browser-dependent, and is it *your* problem to deal with the problems of external pages? As a rule of thumn, if a page is bad, don’t link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way in which I ( the writer of static webpage ) can dictate that when clicked, a hyperlink should be opened in a certain browser ( if available on client machine ) ?

No, there isn't.

Things you *can* do:

1. Have a page that, when loaded, detects the browser using JavaScript and then takes the user to the desired target page based on what browser they're using. This is not usually a good idea, normally you'd want to detect the specific features that a page requires rather than detecting the browser, but if you *have* to detect the browser, you can do that with `navigation.userAgent`.
2. Same as #1, but using the server (the server has access to the user agent string). But that's not a "static" web page anymore.
3. You can write a "protocol handler" which you install on the browser where the choice is being made, and then use your custom protocol to open the target browser. But we're now *well* afield of "static webpage" and the users would have to install your protocol handler in their browser. Not *really* an option.

Overall, though, the **best** thing is to just have one page that works cross-browser, not individual browser-specific pages (that's very 1996), by detecting what features that browser provides and using them.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. But there is one crucial factor that I missed to mention in my question above and its that the external pages are third party websites, I can't really control them or change them to be cross-browser compatible. But in this case, if I am reading you right, there is not much we can do.

Comment: @Summer: Then it would have to be approach #1: Detect what browser the visitor is using (with JavaScript) and update the link to take them to the correct site. I'm really surprised that there are still browser-specific sites out there.